# Dont understand why the answer is this answer

Tags: javafx

Write the invocation (method name with arguments) needed to display the outline of a square whose sides are 60 pixels and whose top right corner is located at (100,200).

the answer is: drawRect(40,200,60,60)

I understand the 60,60, but I dont see how the answer is 40, 200. These are the x and y coordinates right? Can someone explain this to me.

Comment: Top ***right***

Comment: As @James_D and you said, those are the coordinates for the top right corner, `drawRect()` takes its `x` and `y` as the top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is self explainig, but I need to write 30 characters :D

[image]